# How to trim text on textformfield onchange value

Tags: validation, flutter

I want to trim text on TextFormField on value change, for user to input name. User only allowed to type full name, without extra whitespaces between words. (e.g : Myname Isromeo)

I have already using TextEditingController but still not working properly. Here my snippet code to achieve my goal

```
final myController = TextEditingController();

...

return new TextFormField(
      onChanged: (value){
        myController..text = value.trim()
          ..selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: myController.text.length);
      },
      controller: myController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      style: FormStyles.inputStyles(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCACCCF))),
        hintText: 'hint',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
        hintStyle: FormStyles.hintStyles(),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCACCCF)),),
        errorStyle: FormStyles.errorStyles(),
      ),
    );
```

The code above working fine if I only type whitespace, but after I type whitespace after first word, the cursor move to first character. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got my own solution, maybe not the best, but at least it works perfectly!
I decided to create my own input formatter and using `RegExp` to achieve my goal. 
Here my custom formatter

```
class NameInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter{
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {

    if(newValue.text.length > 0){
      TextEditingValue textEditingValue = newValue.copyWith(
          text: newValue.text.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+"), ' ')
      );

      return TextEditingValue(
        text: textEditingValue.text,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
          offset: textEditingValue.text.length,
        ),
      );
    }

    return newValue;

  }

}
```

If you have better solution, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` for input text as you want ignore with `RegExp`.

```
      TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Title",
        ),
        inputFormatters: [
          BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[ ]"))
        ],
      )
```

For more you can refer this : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html

Comment: thanks for your response @Amit, I have tried your solution, but I cannot add whitespace between words.

Comment: You mean you want same like this "Myname Isromeo", you don't want allow user to enter space start and end of that name right ?

Comment: yes I do, but your solution cant add space between Myname and Isromeo

Comment: I have try case with trim onChance, it happens same like you, cursor issue.

Comment: yeah, btw thanks for your response. I will update/post when I found a solution. Thanks!